# Mobile Home Shower Wall Replacement

Tags: shower

My husband and I own a mobile home and the shower walls need repair. I have been trying to find out what they are made of so I can look up what products to buy for the replacement.

The walls from the shower pan to ceiling are 90". Back wall is 59" and both side walls are 36". I also haven't been able to find anything in this size range. Then again, without knowing which material to look at, its difficult to really search.

We want to just do a simple replacement of parts. Something budget but that will get the job done.

Does anyone know what material this is?

[image: Shower stall]

Answer (score 0):

The material you are looking for is acrylic.

You can get panels in various sizes, cut them to fit and glue them on with an adhesive.

You can buy kits that come with multiple pieces including the sides, back and trim pieces.

Answer (score 0):

Look for a Mobile Home supply store.

They have all the stuff for mobile homes that you don't find in the big box home stores.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really matter what the material is *now*--manufacturers use the cheapest thing available, which is why it now looks like that.

I'd look for a proper **acrylic shower surround** panel kit that could be made to work. It'll have molded-in shelves and a washcloth bar. Your size seems right on par for a 3 ft. by 5 ft. kit, which is standard tub size.

Otherwise, **FRP (fiber-reinforced plastic) panels** would do well. They're readily available and home improvement centers.